# Totals for several select options with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to get a total for all the selected options and have the answer rounded to one decimal place. Note I dont work with JQuery
Thanks in advance

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <title>Testing Code</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Scores</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
            <select id="item1" name="item1">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="0.1">10%</option>
                <option value="0.2">20%</option>
                <option value="0.25">25%</option>
                <option value="0.3">30%</option>
                <option value="0.4">40%</option>
                <option value="0.5">50%</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>
            <select id="item2" name="item2">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="0.1">10%</option>
                <option value="0.2">20%</option>
                <option value="0.25">25%</option>
                <option value="0.3">30%</option>
                <option value="0.4">40%</option>
                <option value="0.5">50%</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>
            <select id="item3" name="item3">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="0.1">10%</option>
                <option value="0.2">20%</option>
                <option value="0.25">25%</option>
                <option value="0.3">30%</option>
                <option value="0.4">40%</option>
                <option value="0.5">50%</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Total:</td>
        <td>Caculated Total here in 1 decimal place</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what did you try?

Comment: I have the below working with JQuery

<script>
    $( "#item1,#item2,#item3).change(function() {


    var totalsum = 0;
    var v1 = $("#item1 option:selected").val();
    var v2 = $("#item2 option:selected").val();
    var v3 = $("#item3 option:selected").val();

    var a =  $.isNumeric(v1) ?  parseFloat(v1) : 0;
    var b =  $.isNumeric(v2) ?  parseFloat(v2) : 0;
    var c =  $.isNumeric(v3) ?  parseFloat(v3) : 0;


    var alltotal = (a + b + c);
    var totalsum = alltotal.toFixed(1);
    $("#total").text(totalsum);
    });
</script>

Comment: So you say you do not work with jQuery, but you have a jQuery soluiton?

Answer (score 1):

Attach change event handler and calculate the sum and update on each change.

```
// get all select elements within table
// and convert it into array
// for older browser use [].slice.call(...
var s = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#item1,#item2,#item3'));

// iterate over elements
s.forEach(function(ele) {
  // bind change event handler to the element
  ele.addEventListener('change', function() {
    // get td to be updated and calculate sum by using reduce method
    document.querySelector('#total').textContent = s.reduce(function(sum, e) {
      return sum + Number(e.value);
      // set initial value as 0
    }, 0).toFixed(1); // limit to one decimal place
  })
})
```

```js
// get all select elements within table
// and convert it into array
// for older browser use [].slice.call(...
var s = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#item1,#item2,#item3'));

// iterate over elements
s.forEach(function(ele) {
  // bind change event handler to the element
  ele.addEventListener('change', function() {
    // get td to be updated and calculate sum by using reduce method
    document.querySelector('#total').textContent = s.reduce(function(sum, e) {
      return sum + Number(e.value);
      // set initial value as 0
    }, 0).toFixed(1); // limit to one decimal place
  })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
  <title>Testing Code</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Scores</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
          <select id="item1" name="item1">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="0.1">10%</option>
            <option value="0.2">20%</option>
            <option value="0.25">25%</option>
            <option value="0.3">30%</option>
            <option value="0.4">40%</option>
            <option value="0.5">50%</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>
          <select id="item2" name="item2">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="0.1">10%</option>
            <option value="0.2">20%</option>
            <option value="0.25">25%</option>
            <option value="0.3">30%</option>
            <option value="0.4">40%</option>
            <option value="0.5">50%</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>
          <select id="item3" name="item3">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="0.1">10%</option>
            <option value="0.2">20%</option>
            <option value="0.25">25%</option>
            <option value="0.3">30%</option>
            <option value="0.4">40%</option>
            <option value="0.5">50%</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Total:</td>
        <td id="total">0</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```